# iOS 7, Done button in embedded video doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I have a webview application developed in Xcode 5.  I have a 2 `UIViewControllers`: `viewController` and `secondviewController`.  The `secondviewController` is used to open video.   The `secondViewController` has a "Back" button that will bring user back to `viewController` (1st view).  It works fine in iOS 6 or iOS 5 but doesn't work on iOS 7.  When I clicked the "Done" button from video player, it brought me back to `secondViewController` where I can see the "Back" Button  for a second.  I tried to click on it, it didn't bring me back to 1st view, it plays the video again.

Here is the code. It is pretty basic.

In `AppDelegate`:

```
window.rootViewController = viewController;  
[window addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In `ViewController`:

```
SecondViewController *controllerIphone = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
//pass the URL to the second controller.
controllerIphone.webViewUrl = URL;
controllerIphone.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve; 
self presentViewController:controllerIphone animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In `SecondViewController`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_webViewUrl]];
}

- (IBAction)doDismiss:(id)sender {
  [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  
}
```

I found that it `(IBAction)doDismiss:(id)sender` doesn't fire.  If I commented `window.rootViewController = viewController;` out from `AppDelegate`, it works but I can't rotate my view.

Comment: Hi, are you making use of an `MPMoviePlayerController` to play the video?

Comment: No, I just open video from its default player. Not making use of MPMoviePlayerController